# Get an Array in results from SQL in PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays

i'm doing

```
$sql = $_SESSION['data']->bySQL("SELECT * FROM worlds WHERE field='shippingLicenseItemName'");
```

and then printing result(i know it is very simple but i'm learning by myself through this site)

```
echo nl2br(print_r($sql, true));
```

and in result i'm getting array like this :

```
 Array
(
[atlantis] => Array
(
[shippingLicenseItemName] => pkg_atlantisXfer
)

[australia] => Array
(
[shippingLicenseItemName] => pkg_australiaXfer
)

[avalon] => Array
(
[shippingLicenseItemName] => pkg_avalonXfer
)
)
```

but i want the results like : 
`World : "atlantis" and item : "shippingLicenseItemName" and code is : "pkg_atlantisxfer"`

`World : "australia" and item : "shippingLicenseItemName" and code is : "pkg_australiaxfer"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know where you found the `bySQL` property, it seems to be returning the data keyed by a column on its own, making things a tad more complicated.

But i'ts nothing you cannot solve with a couple of loops :

```
foreach($sql as $o_key=>$o_data) {
   foreach($o_data as $i_key=>$i_data) {
     print "World $o_key and item : $i_key and code is $i_data <br />"l
   }
}
```

Comment: thank a bunch **^_^** hexblot. i was thinking to use foreach but every time get stuck on second loop where you use `$o_data as` **$i_key =>$i_data**
.
thank once again.
i also know there is another method to perform that function is something like :

     `$vSQL .= "SELECT * FROM worlds WHERE field='shippingLicenseItemName' " ;`
 `$vReturn = @$_SESSION['data']->bySQL($vSQL);`
  `$vResult = array();`

But i don't know much about it